# Reading xml file using Python lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I'm reading the below xml file using Python lxml but could not get to the node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <serial id>1234</serialid>
        <key>
            <Product>Test Producet</Product>
            <Start>Jan</Start>
        <key>
    </license>
</licenses>
```

Python code

```
tree = etree.parse('test.slf')
root = tree.getroot()
print 'root = ', root[0][0].findall('key')
#print 'root findall = ', root.getroottree('key')
for node in root.findall('key'):
        print node
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for node in tree.xpath('//key'):
    print node
```

btw, there are 2 typos in your xml: take out the space in opening tag of `<serial id>` and add `/` to closing `<key>`